# CMS/PKCS#7: specifying signatureAlgorithm with digest?

Tags: hash, public-key-infrastructure, digital-signature, algorithm, asn1

I'm confused about algorithm selection for Cryptographic Message Syntax (a.k.a. CMS, PKCS#7) signed objects ([RFC5652 Section 5.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652#section-5.1)).

The `SignerInfo` structure ([RFC5652 Section 5.3](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652#section-5.3)) has two separate algorithm identifier fields:

- `digestAlgorithm` for the digest (hash) algorithm and its associated parameters, and
- `signatureAlgorithm` for the signature algorithm and its associated parameters.

(This is in contrast to certificates ([RFC5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280)), CRLs ([RFC5280](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5280)), and certification requests ([RFC2986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2986), [RFC4211](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4211)) which don't have a separate digest algorithm field.)

For the `signatureAlgorithm` field, you can choose `rsaEncryption` ([RFC3370 Section 3.2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3370#section-3.2)), or you can choose a variant that itself specifies a digest algorithm, e.g., `sha1WithRSAEncryption` or `md5WithRSAEncryption`.

**What is the relationship between the signature algorithm's digest algorithm and the digest algorithm specified in the `digestAlgorithm` field?**

Specific sub-questions:

- Suppose `digestAlgorithm` contains `sha-1` ([RFC3370 Section 2.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3370#section-2.1)).  Is there any difference between choosing `rsaEncryption` vs. `sha1WithRSAEncryption` for the `signatureAlgorithm` field?
- What happens if I put `sha-1` in `digestAlgorithm` but choose `md5WithRSAEncryption` for `signatureAlgorithm`?